# Validación if en OnpostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Estoy desarrollando una app en android studio, en la cual consumo webservices, tengo mi metodo login el cual me regresa un string con un `true` y un `false`, lo que yo necesito es que en el `OnpostExecute` yo pueda hacer un if para comparar lo que me regresar esa llamada en el `doInbackground`, y en el `onpostexecute` hacer la comparacion, ahorita ya estoy implementado un if, si entra pero si yo obtengo un `false` de mi webservices no me muestra el mensaje de error.

Mi Activity, método `Assyntasck`:

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String Result = "";

        Result = webService.Login(editTextUsername,editTextPassword," ");
        return Result;
    }

    @Override
    //Make Progress Bar visible
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Loding...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    //Once WebService returns response
    protected void onPostExecute(String Result) {
        super.onPostExecute(Result);

        if((Result) == "True") {

            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inicio de Sesion Erroneo, Favor revisa" +
                                                   "los datos Ingresado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else {


            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gracias por Iniciar Sesion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Menu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    }
```

Método en el cual se hace el llamado a los Webservices:

```
public static String Login(String Usuario,
                               String Contrasena,
                               String Conexion)
    {
        String Resultado = "";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9021/","Login");
        request.addProperty("Usuario", Usuario);
        request.addProperty("Contrasena", Contrasena);
        request.addProperty("Conexion", Conexion);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes=false;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,7000);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9021/Login", envelope);
        //String ss = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        Resultado=response.toString();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
        //menu.errored = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema en la comparación podría ser por dos situaciones:

La comparación entre cadenas debe hacerse con el método `equals`:

```
if(Result.equals("True")) {
    // código aquí
}
```

No coincide la capitalización de `Resultado` y la cadena `"True"`, eso se puede solucionar comparando las dos con letras minúsculas:

```
if(Result.toLowerCase().equals("True")) {
    // código aquí
}
```

Si eso no funciona trata de debuggear la aplicación para ver si el web service está devolviendo el valor que esperas.

Comment: lo voy a probar, gracias

Comment: si funciono gracias